# My pip install venv installing modules for all users instead of creating just one venv in creating project

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-venv, cmder

While creating a new environment **venv** in a new project I'm typing in the command line:
'''python -m venv new_prj'''
After that, I'm installing some **pip module**
''' pip install django==2 ''' - for example
and it's automatically change all my other projects with **venv** and install that '''django==2''' to all projects instead of just installing to my **new_prj** dir
How can I solve this problem?
I'm working on windows 10

Comment: After creating your new env, are you "activating" it?

Comment: I didn't, How can I do it on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly try activating before installing any package.

Generally a venv needs to be activated before accessing its modules and in windows you can do that by executing the bat file in the Scripts folder in the venv.

You can try the follwing

```
C:\Users\'Username'\path\to\new_prj\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have done as you wrote above but still got the same result in all my other projects this module was reinstall too.

Comment: Are you using same venv for all other projects?

Comment: It could be, I don't actually know. How can I check it?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've just done. 
I followed by steps from here: https://mothergeo-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/how-to/venv-win.html